# Segmentation fault C language strcat()

Tags: c, lexer

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char lexer_string[] = "echo Hello %a% %b%";
    char temp_variable_name[128] = "...";
    int variable_buff = 0;
    int check = 0;
    int detect_start = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(lexer_string); i++) {
        // printf("%c\n", lexer_string[i]);
        if (lexer_string[i] == '%' && variable_buff == 0) {
            check = 1;
            variable_buff = 1;
        }
        if (variable_buff == 1) {
            if (lexer_string[i] == '%' && detect_start == 0) {
                detect_start = 1;
                printf("%%\x20");
            }
            else if (lexer_string[i] == '%' && detect_start == 1) {
                detect_start = 0;
                printf(" \%\n");
            }
            else if (lexer_string[i] != '%') {
                printf("%c", lexer_string[i]);
                strcat(temp_variable_name, lexer_string[i]);
                strcat(temp_variable_name, ' ');
            }
        }
        if (lexer_string[i] == '%' && variable_buff == 1 && check != 1) {
            variable_buff = 0;
        }
        if (lexer_string[i] == '\0') {
            printf("Wynik:%s\n", temp_variable_name);
            break;
        }
        check = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is my simple code, when i use the function strcat() my code stops working. I tried change size of char array's, changed position of function in program (i move them to end but still doesn't work.)

Comment: you are trying to concatenate char to a string, not a string to a string

Comment: Enable compiler warnings.

Comment: You could write a function to append a char to a string, something like `void append_char(char *s, char c) { size_t len = strlen(s); s[len++] = c; s[len] = '\0'; }`. (Note: not safe against buffer overflow.)

Comment: You should `#include <string.h>` for strcat and heed your compiler warnings.